# Spring Data Hibernate Envers Problem with UUID Primary Key

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, hibernate-envers

I'm using Spring Data's Envers Wrapper and the following library versions:

Spring Boot 2.6.6
Hibernate Core 5.6.7
Hibernate Envers 5.6.7

And I have the following entity:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@Audited
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "fm_sqs_message", schema = "shared")
@TypeDefs({
        @TypeDef(name = "json", typeClass = JsonStringType.class),
        @TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class)
})
public class FmSQSMessageEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private UUID id;

    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    @Column(name = "message_body")
    private String messageBody;
}
```

This is the Envers table generated for the entity:

```
CREATE TABLE if NOT EXISTS shared.revinfo
(
    rev      int4 NOT NULL,
    revtstmp int8 NULL,
    CONSTRAINT revinfo_pkey PRIMARY KEY (rev)
);

CREATE TABLE if NOT EXISTS shared.fm_sqs_message_aud
(
    id               uuid NOT NULL,
    rev              int4 NOT NULL,
    revtype          int2 NULL,
    message_body     uuid NULL,
    message_type     varchar(255) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fm_sqs_message_aud_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id, rev)
);

ALTER TABLE shared.fm_sqs_message_aud DROP CONSTRAINT IF EXISTS fkjh3gcaqcwg2r1g20duafkejf4;

ALTER TABLE shared.fm_sqs_message_aud
    ADD CONSTRAINT fkjh3gcaqcwg2r1g20duafkejf4 FOREIGN KEY (rev) REFERENCES urbanise_mri_integration.revinfo (rev);
```

Now when I try to insert a new entity in my original table I get the following exception:

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Unable to perform beforeTransactionCompletion callback: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute statement; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to perform beforeTransactionCompletion callback: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute statement
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:331) ~[spring-orm-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:233) ~[spring-orm-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:566) ~[spring-orm-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:743) ~[spring-tx-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711) ~[spring-tx-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:654) ~[spring-tx-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:407) ~[spring-tx-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:753) ~[spring-aop-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:698) ~[spring-aop-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at com.urbanise.mri.service.fm.sqs.FMSQSMessageService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7c1c0b01.create(<generated>) ~[main/:na]
    at com.urbanise.mri.component.schedule.TestSchedule.test(TestSchedule.java:36) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:84) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset$$$capture(FutureTask.java:305) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to perform beforeTransactionCompletion callback: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue$BeforeTransactionCompletionProcessQueue.beforeTransactionCompletion(ActionQueue.java:960) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.beforeTransactionCompletion(ActionQueue.java:525) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2426) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:449) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:183) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:40) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:281) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:562) ~[spring-orm-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:154) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:188) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1411) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1394) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.envers.internal.synchronization.AuditProcess.doBeforeTransactionCompletion(AuditProcess.java:178) ~[hibernate-envers-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.envers.internal.synchronization.AuditProcessManager$1.doBeforeTransactionCompletion(AuditProcessManager.java:47) ~[hibernate-envers-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue$BeforeTransactionCompletionProcessQueue.beforeTransactionCompletion(ActionQueue.java:954) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    ... 31 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:115) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:37) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:200) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:46) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3375) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3908) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.lambda$executeActions$1(ActionQueue.java:478) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:721) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:475) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:344) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:40) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1407) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    ... 35 common frames omitted
**Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type uuid: "{}"
    at** org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2675) ~[postgresql-42.3.3.jar:42.3.3]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2365) ~[postgresql-42.3.3.jar:42.3.3]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:355) ~[postgresql-42.3.3.jar:42.3.3]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:490) ~[postgresql-42.3.3.jar:42.3.3]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:408) ~[postgresql-42.3.3.jar:42.3.3]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:166) ~[postgresql-42.3.3.jar:42.3.3]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:134) ~[postgresql-42.3.3.jar:42.3.3]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:197) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    ... 47 common frames omitted
```

I've debugged the application and just before the insert Hibernate correctly populates the UUID field.

Any idea what may be causing this?

Comment: The problem seems to be with the messageBody column which is of type jsonb. Does envers support it?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a limitation of Hibernate 5 running into an issue of how Hibernate Envers builds it's model. If you want to model this, you will have to use Hibernate 6.